# Reactjs Design with expensive API calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a SPA that allows users to upload data and view calculations based on the data.

I use a parent component that is polled every 2 seconds that fetches each item in the data list via AJAX. I iterate through each item on the list, which invokes a child react component which makes an expensive API call to retrieve the calculations and displays it in a table.

This is the code for the child component:

```
var DisplayRow = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return (
            {data: [] }
            );

    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.loadData()
    },

    loadData: function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tables/" + this.props.columns + "/stats/",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    this.setState({data: data});
                    console.log("mounted");

                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
    },

/*
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log(nextProps.columns)
        console.log(this.props.columns)
        return nextProps.columns !== this.props.columns;
    },
    */

    render: function(){


        var rows = this.state.data.map(function(item){
        var titles = []
        var vals = []
        for(var key in item){
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                titles.push(key)
                vals.push(item[key])
                }
        }
        return (
            <table className="table-hover table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <DisplayStuff stuff={titles} />
            <DisplayStuff stuff={vals} />
            </tbody>
            </table>
            );

        });


        return (
            <div className="yep">

            <h2> {this.props.name} </h2>
                {rows}
            </div>
            );
```

What's a good way to design it so the polling on the list is fine, but the expensive API calls only happens once (unless the initial list is changed e.g. more data is added)?

I toyed with shouldComponentUpdate, but I call the API before the rendering happens, so the calls are still made, and also if I refresh my page after the initial data loading then the tables aren't rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can call and **cache** the expensive API calls in the parent component. Then simply pass that data to DisplayRow as props

Comment: Is there a specific way to cache it? My parent component is polling the first API call which I subsequently use to make the more expensive ones.

Comment: there's no specific way. It's appropriate for parent to cache it.